# what automation tool can be used to automate Google blockly code?

Tags: blockly

Recently We have implemented Google blockly in our application. I need to automate the UI but selenium does not support for Google blockly.

So please suggest me a automation tool for the Google blockly UI.

Comment: What did you intend to test there? Or what do you expect to automate?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not a way to automate the UI as much as an idea for automating the process of adding a predefined set of blocks to a new workspace.  Have a look at making Custom blocks, from there you should be able to create a subset of blocks that you can add to your menu.  The demo's seem to cover doing all of this, you only have to understand how to then write it into your application.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a great answer, but try Autohotkey